# Android get extra value from json except listitems

Tags: android, json

My application is a news application. I have a listview population data from json-php-mysql. 
I want to get the number of new records of other news categories. For example, while listing economy news I want to show count of new sport news at the footer over sport icon. 
Here is my codes: 
PHP code

```
while($b=mysql_fetch_assoc($myquery)){
$news[] = array("header" => $b['header'], "newsid" => $b['newsid']);
}
echo json_encode($news);
```

my java code

```
 class Loadnews extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category",activecat));
        // getting JSON string from URL
        String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_CATEGORY, "GET",
                params);
        return json;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
        try {
            news = new JSONArray(json);
            if (news != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < news.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = news.getJSONObject(i);
                    String header= c.getString(TAG_HEADER);
                     String newsid= c.getString(TAG_NEWSID);
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_HEADER, HEADER);
                     map.put(TAG_NEWSID, newsid);
                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    newslist.add(map);
                }
                mAdapter = new CategoryListAdapter(mainactivity.this,newslist);
                lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            } else {
                Log.d("NEWS: ", "null");
            }
} catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}}
```

I dont want to run another asynctask for getting new news. Is there a way to get count in this function? 
P.S: variable names may be incorrect because I tried to simplify the code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a Map which contains the header and the number of news. 
The Map match the header and the number of news which have the same header.
For exemple ,:

```
HashMap<String,Integer> myMapCounter = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : myMapCounter.entrySet()) {
      if(entry.getKey().equals(header))
      {
         entry.setValue(entry.getValue()+1)
      }
   }
```

I don't really understand the question. So I hope it's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for help. Think facebook app. I need to get notification count and show at action bar when I get news feed.